# How to integrate the livesdk messenger in my app in windows phone using c#.net

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, live-connect-sdk, live-sdk

In my windows phone app, I want to allow the exchange of information between other users of the same app and that information will be used in creating certain records.

does the livesdk supports the messaging through code in windows phone ?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Live SDK does not expose the Messenger API. You have access to the following API sets:

- [Hotmail API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535.aspx) (calendars and contacts)
- [Identity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826537.aspx) (user identity and related metadata)
- [SkyDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx) (storage)

Comment: Can I use Facebook chat or gtalk?

Comment: Not through the Live SDK. You will need to either find third-party libraries that support those services or implement your own wrapper for the APIs.